# Search from column with partial matches on values of array on ROOM

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I have a huge list of postal codes that I need to implement a search feature for.
What Id like to do is:

with any of these string the result **"2695-650, São João da Talha"** should appear:
"2695"
"2695-650"
"2695 650"
"São João"
"sAo joA da TaLH"
"sao talha"
"talh joa"
"joao talha"
"talha 650 joao"

I made an edit text and implemented its listner like so

```
    txtSearch = root.findViewById(R.id.txtPostalCodeSearch)
    txtSearch?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) { }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            var string = s.toString()

            if(string.isNullOrBlank())
                viewModel.getPostalCodes()
            else{
                var filterWord = "%" + string.toLowerCase() + "%"
                viewModel.getFilteredPostalCodes(filterWord)
            }
        }
    })
```

And the room dao query im currently using is:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PostalCode WHERE lower(full_postal_code) LIKE :filterString")
fun SearchQuery(filterString: String) : List<PostalCode?>?
```

Obviously this wont work as I want it obviously,

I also tried to split the search string in words and search from an array like so.

```
var filterWords = string.toLowerCase().split(" ", "-").toMutableList()
viewModel.getFilteredPostalCodes(filterWords)
```

And from the room dao query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PostalCode WHERE lower(full_postal_code) IN (:filterStrings)")
fun SearchQueryFromArray(vararg filterStrings: String) : List<PostalCode?>?
```

but this fails in the fact that each value of the array doesn't permit a partial match

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried Auto Complete TextView?

Comment: I should've specified it but, Im using this textview to update the a recyclerview that is directly underneath it, an auto complete textview wont help much here.

Comment: how big is the list? you could load it fully and use search to limit visible items in memory

Comment: the list has 367.8k items and growing.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's unusual idea, but consider using [RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery). It should be used only if you have some problems defining static query text. But it seems it could be the case.
Main idea - to get dynamic query text depending on your `filterWords` list (since you want all words from list match to the result):

```
select * from PostalCode where 
full_postal_code LIKE ? AND full_postal_code LIKE ?  ...
```

(`?` used in RawQuery as in a raw Sqlite - as a parameter placeholder - each `LIKE` statement for each search word).

So in your Dao method:

```
@RawQuery
fun getUser(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<PostalCode?>?
```

Then you should add auxiliary method (could be put into dao as well) that should generate this `SupportSQLiteQuery` object with needed query string (it's not optimal, you can clean it, replace with StringBuilder whatever):

```
fun findUser(filterWords: List<String>): List<PostalCode?>? {
    var queryString = "select * from PostalCode where 1 = 1 " // <- just for easier concat, change it as you like
    repeat(list.size) {searchString += " and user_name LIKE ?"}
    val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery(queryString, filterWords.toTypedArray()) // <- second parameter should be array
    return getUser(query)
}
```

Then you can call this `findUser` method from your viewModel/repository.